# How to get value from pending promise from mongoose model(model.findOne())

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, promise, nestjs

I have problem: i cant resolve promise when i need, with this part of code, queries done correct. I use NestJs if it helps. I need it to return a user object.
Here's that i've done so far.

```
private async findUserByLogin(userLogin: string): Promise<Object> {
          const res = await this.userModel.findOne({ login: userLogin }).exec();
          return res;
        }
    async create(task: Task): Promise<Task> {
         let userIds;
         userIds.push(this.findUserByLogin(task.login)); 
         console.log(userLogins);
    }
```

this.findUserByLogin(user.login) returns Promise{  }, but then i try to return it as result of "create" it returns a mongoose model(object), as i expected before.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I follow but I guest just need to await for that promise, as you did in the `findOne` call

```js
userIds.push(await this.findUserByLogin(task.login))
```

btw that's just javascript stuff, not related with any framework